# SheetJS XLSX.read ends up with Page Unresponsive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, xlsx, sheetjs

I am trying to read a xlsx file that has a size of 3000KB  and convert it to JSON using SheetJS, but when I read the file I seem to get a chrome 'Page Unresponsive error', clicking wait on the error everytime I upload a file is not ideal.

How can I resolve this issue?

```
onChange(event) {
  this.file = event.target.files ? event.target.files[0] : null;
  this.uploaded = true;
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file);
  reader.onload = function () {
    const data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
    const wb = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'array', sheets: ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2'] });
    this.summary = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(wb.Sheets.Summary);
    this.weeklyDetails = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(wb.Sheets['Weekly Details']);
    console.log(this.weeklyDetails);
  };
},
```

[image]

Comment: Look at your CPU. I'm guessing the file was too much for your browser (SheetJS was over-exerted) so the browser froze. You could try using Web Workers to work in the background and prevent page freeze. Or just use the server-side (if you could).

Comment: "clicking wait on the error everytime I upload a file is not ideal." Does it work after clicking the wait error button? And are you happy with waiting? Maybe a Promise could be used to avoid render blocking happening. Or require smaller files.